# Filter collection (array of objects) based on other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, underscore.js

I have the following problem. I wolud like to filter this fruitsCollection based on fruits array. 
I would like to be the result was that, for example :

```
     filteredFruits1 [ all fruits with the 
                       exception of those which are in  
                       fruitsToCut array
                     ]
```

Example:

```
var fruitsToCut = [ 'egzotic', 'other'],
    fruitsCollection = [ {name: papaya, type: 'egzotic'}, 
                         {name: orange, type: 'citrus'}, 
                         {name: lemon, type: 'citrus'}
                       ]
```

Maybe some underscore function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a modern browser, you can use the native [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
fruitsCollection.filter(function(fruit) {
  return fruitsToCut.indexOf(fruit.type) === -1;
} );
```

Otherwise, you can use the [underscore filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) in pretty much the same way:

```
_.filter( fruitsCollection, function(fruit) {
  return !_.contains(fruitsToCut, fruit.type);
} );
```

Also, your fruit names need to be quoted:

```
fruitsCollection = [ {name: 'papaya', type: 'egzotic'}, 
                         {name: 'orange', type: 'citrus'}, 
                         {name: 'lemon', type: 'citrus'}
                       ];
```

Comment: Thank You :) -  it works great, I have to read again all this underscore function. 
Yes, of course I forgot quotes for fruits names ;)